Searching for an old anime with a red carriage
I don't have that much information on this but the main character had a prosthetic arm and the only scene i remember is him being in a red carriage with the villain/his father? I'm not sure. There were flashbacks of a three or the carriage was near one im not sure.

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. - How old was the main character? What was their name?

Probaby Ed and his father Van Hohenheim from Full Metal Alchemist, but I can't find an image capture of them riding in a carriage.  I do seem to remember the scene, however.

If possible, what do you mean by an "old" anime? 2000s? 90s? 80s? 70s? Perhaps easier to answer, do you know approximately when you watched it?

Incidentally, having just finished rewatching it, I can say there is not such a scene in Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood, so we can eliminate that from contention. There is a tree, though, so maybe FMA03?
